# Two NSFetchedResultsController, Two Views, One Entity-Type

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm currently banging my head around this problem:

I have two views on the same entity. The first one lets the user CRUD the Entity (TouchModelVariable), the second one lets the user assign it to a another entity (TouchModelConstraintTerm). The second view is only for selection. But when I delete entities via the first view, upon scrolling in the second view the app crashes with an "index out of bounds" error.

Detailed explanation: First the first controller, the CRUD one.

```
MSPUIManagedDocument *doc = self.document;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:MODEL_ENTITY_TOUCH_MODEL_VARIABLE inManagedObjectContext:doc.managedObjectContext];
fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription;
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;

//[NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"touchModel.active"] rightExpression:[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:YES] modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier type:nil options:nil];
// touchModel.active == 1
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"touchModel == %@", self.touchModel, nil];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptior = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptior];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

// nameSectionIndex
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:doc.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"name" cacheName:@"MSPVariablesManagementTableViewController"];
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

NSError *error = nil;
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"MSPVariablesManagementTableViewController"];
if(![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error while fetching <%@>, <%@>", error, [error userInfo]);
}

return fetchedResultsController;
```

The TableView is bound to that controller, as it's described in the book "Pro CoreData for iOS".

The second view uses nearly the same code, but the CacheKeys are different. If I delete entities with the first view, and then navigate through the app to the second view (which *is re-instantiated every time*) the app crashes upon scrolling, because it assumes that the deleted records are there.
I also tried to save the ManagedObjectContext, before entering the second view.

```
CRASH: *** -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (8) beyond bounds (8)
2012-03-17 11:36:48.953 MSPLPSolve[38685:fb03] Stack Trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0192503e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01dc2cd6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x018cda48 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x018cd9b9 +[NSException raise:format:] + 57
    4   CoreData                            0x003ffc23 -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:] + 131
    5   CoreData                            0x004ec260 -[NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:] + 448
    6   MSPLPSolve                          0x0005d820 -[MSPUtilitiesVariablesSelectionTableViewController configureCell:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 128
    7   MSPLPSolve                          0x0003057b -[MSPFetchedResultsTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 283
    8   UIKit                               0x008efc54 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 494
    9   UIKit                               0x008f03ce -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
    10  UIKit                               0x008dbcbd -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1350
    11  UIKit                               0x008ea6f1 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 242
    12  UIKit                               0x00893d21 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 145
... a load of other stuff not in my code ...
```

*BUT* when I save the document completly (closing, reopening) between deleting entities via the first controller and navigating to the second controller - it doesn't crash. Is NSFetchedResultsController caching a loads of stuff in the background? And is there a in depth guide how the caching works and how I have to use it?

Puuuh, thanks for reading this far! Regardless if you have an idea or not!

Mark

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue to me. Try setting the caches to nil on both fetchedResultsControllers to see if it solves your problem, then you can go from there.

Comment: I delete the cache every time and I tried to set the cache to nil - same result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a `performFetch` on your results controller after you altered the model? Also I'm assuming your results controllers delegate methods are implemented correctly.

Comment: The code above is called when the NSFetchedResultsController is accessed (it's in the "get property" method).
Will have to look at the implementation, took it right out of a CoreData Book and implemented the insert/update/delete callbacks into the table as well. Any suggestions what could be wrong?